iOS Camera Freezes and Crashes with MLKit Barcode Scanning in Kotlin Multiplatform
I'm developing an app using Kotlin Multiplatform and Googles MLKit for barcode scanning. I'm unable to create a VisionImage in the captureOutput method of a AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate. When trying, I am encountering periodic freezes every 15 frames for 10 seconds.
In my CameraViewController (iosMain)
class CameraViewController(
    private val onQRCodeDetected: (String) -> Unit
) : UIViewController(null, null), AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegateProtocol {

I overwrite captureOutput
    override fun captureOutput(
        output: AVCaptureOutput,
        didOutputSampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef?,
        fromConnection: AVCaptureConnection
    ) {        
        frameCounter+=1
        logging("CViewC").i { "FRAME #$frameCounter" }

so far everything works perfect. captureOutput gets called each frame in time and logs the framecount. When I add the following line things break.
val visionImage = MLKVisionImage(didOutputSampleBuffer)

Now the first 15 calles of captureOutput are ok. During this duration the preview on the phone works fluent. Then the preview freezes and captureOutput is not called. This lasts for 10 seconds. After the 10 seconds I receive again 15 frames normally. This cicle goes on and the app never crashes.
When I add now the line
CFRelease(didOutputSampleBuffer)

I get a continuous flow of 288 frames until a crash. The crash report indicates that I tried to release an already released buffer(Detected over-release of a CFTypeRef %p (%lu / %s)).
I tried to copy the Buffer:
val copiedBufferVar = nativeHeap.alloc<CMSampleBufferRefVar>()
CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(
    allocator = kCFAllocatorDefault,
    sbuf = didOutputSampleBuffer,
    sampleBufferOut = copiedBufferVar.ptr
)
val visionImage = MLKVisionImage(didOutputSampleBuffer.value)
CFRelease(copiedBufferVar.value)

Since I assumed the Buffers were not released from memory because of the strong reference of the VisionImage to the Buffer. (I don't know if that makes sense - I desperately tried to make sense of something). This resulted in the same thing. A cycle of 15 frames OK and 10 Seconds freeze.
I tried to release the VisionImage from memory by making it nullable and setting it to null after usage. This also change nothing. LLM's recommended using a autoreleasepool but that also didn't help.
So I guess it is a memory problem. I thought my AVCaptureSession takes care of this stuff automatically. I configured it like this. I removed some null checks to keep it shorter here.
@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
private fun setupCaptureSession() {

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession().apply {
        beginConfiguration()
        sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720
    }

    val device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    val input = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(device, null)
    if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input) == true) {
        captureSession?.addInput(input)
    }
    videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput().apply {
        setSampleBufferDelegate(this@CameraViewController, processingQueue)
        videoSettings = mapOf(
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey to NSNumber(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) 
        )
        alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    }
    if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(videoOutput!!) == true) {
        captureSession?.addOutput(videoOutput!!)
    }
    captureSession?.commitConfiguration()
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session = captureSession!!).apply {
        videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    }
}


I had the same issue. What worked for me was calling kotlin.native.runtime.GC.collect() as soon as the MLKVisionImage was no longer needed.
var visionImage: MLKVisionImage? = MLKVisionImage(didOutputSampleBuffer)
// ...
recognizer.processImage(visionImage as MLKCompatibleImageProtocol) { mlkText, nsError ->
  visionImage = null
  kotlin.native.runtime.GC.collect()
 // ...
}



a further complication, but a separate issue was that even with the GC you can't block the queue the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate is running on for long. Solved it by using (coroutines) channel that drops the current frame if the last one has not finished processing yet.
